# Error with activerecord -3.1.11 Could not find table (ActiveRecord::Statement Invalid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, production

Before push my app to heroku, I tested my app in production mode, it works perfectly if its in the development mode, but in production mode I'm getting following error activerecord -3.1.11 Could not find table (ActiveRecord::Statement Invalid).

How to fix this error?

I'm sure that table 'pages' exists.

```
C:\Sites\ecozap>rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/connection_ad
apters/sqlite_adapter.rb:450:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'pages' (ActiveRecord::Statement
Invalid)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/
connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:333:in `columns'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/
connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/
connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:712:in `yield'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:712:in `default'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:712:in `columns'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:728:in `column_names'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:741:in `column_methods_hash'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1118:in `all_attributes_exists?'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:892:in `respond_to?'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:193:in `valid_scope_name?'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:175:in `scope'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/app/models/page.rb:22:in `<class:Page>'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/app/models/page.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `constantize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:148:in `_default_wrap_model'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:167:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:128:in `inherited'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/config.ru:8:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`instance_eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`initialize'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Sites/ecozap/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`parse_file'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in`app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in`wrapped_app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in`start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, your table exists, but probably only in development database. It doesn't exist in production database, which is different by default.

You should either run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

to migrate your production database or edit `database.yml` file to set your production database to be the same as development database.

Comment: What this does exactly? Do not want to lose the database. Is it a version problem?

Comment: @user3152808 check out edited answer. You won't lose your db.

Comment: Ok thanks Marke Lipka I check out the command and I received this answer:

    C:\Sites\ecozap>heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate --app ecozap
    Running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8487
    Migrating to CreateShoes (20110523234805)
    Migrating to AddPhotoColumnsToShoe (20110524154326)
    Migrating to ShoeSize (20110524183119)
    Migrating to AddProviderIdToShoe (20110524195410)
    Migrating to CreateProviders (20110524205736)
    Migrating to AddBlockToProviders (20110526154032)
    Migrating to CreateUsers (20110529202922)

Comment: Then I run the server and I'm getting following error:

  
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:450:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'pages' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:333:in `columns'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95: ETC

Comment: @user3152808 if you want to test it locally, you should run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate`, like I wrote.

Comment: My ruby and rails command prompt doesn´t recognize this command

Comment: @user3152808 And it shouldn't. You should type it in your OS command line.

Comment: @user3152808 did you try it? Did it help?

Comment: Can you help me Marek?

Comment: @FrankyCutty post your another question as actual question instead of posting it as an answer and unaccepting my answer (which is the correct one).

Comment: Sorry Marek, it is done ;), ¿how to solve this problem?