# Is it necessary to migrate the data base for update the app on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, push

This app, "ecozap: http://www.ecozap.es/" was developed by another developer five years ago, it is relased, I have to make design changes and css styles ...

The app is running on heroku version v174.

Is it necessary to migrate the db for update and push the app on heroku?

I only changed styles and added images.

This is my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

staging:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/staging.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', "= 3.1.11"
#gem "rake", "= 0.8.7"
gem 'racc'
# gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'acts_as_list', '>= 0.1.0'
#gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
gem 'RedCloth', '>= 3.301'
gem 'carmen', :git => 'git://github.com/alvatarc/carmen.git', :branch => '0.2.x'
#gem 'carmen'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'http_accept_language'
gem 'right_aws'
gem 'exception_notification'#, '3.0.1'#añadido

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '= 2.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '= 2.7.1'
  gem 'rspec'
  #gem 'annotate-models'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => 'ruby'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '= 2.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '= 2.7.1'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork', '= 0.9.0.rc9'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

When I push to heroku I´m getting the following error:

```
C:\Sites\ecozap>heroku logs --app ecozap
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `each'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `inject'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706553+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/ac
tion_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (No
MethodError)
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `build'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/engine.rb:447:in `app'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `require'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.706975+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.707423+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.707423+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.707423+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.707423+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.707423+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-28T09:31:23.707423+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-28T09:31:25.113332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed
to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2014-01-28T09:31:25.113517+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2014-01-28T09:31:25.239226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-28T09:31:25.254967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-28T09:31:25.256579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-01-28T09:31:26.892077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-01-28T09:31:29.944119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server
-p 15889`
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3-ruby (>= 0) more than on
ce.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (= 2.7.0) more than
once.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec (>= 0) more than once.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583428+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583232+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-core (= 2.7.1) more than o
nce.
2014-01-28T09:31:33.583428+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you
change the version of just one of them later.
2014-01-28T09:31:44.462215+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-28T09:31:44.462215+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-01-28T09:31:44.462215+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.11 application starting in production on http:
//0.0.0.0:15889
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `inject'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `build'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.462215+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.11/lib/ac
tion_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build': undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module (No
MethodError)
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `block in build'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:112:in `each'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/engine.rb:447:in `app'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.462215+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:8:in `require'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.464071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.464071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.11/
lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.464071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-01-28T09:31:44.463612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/
rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-28T09:31:46.058892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-28T09:31:46.069301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-28T09:31:47.241185+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 87.218.164.248 - - [28/Jan/2014:09:31:47 +0000] "GET /?l
ocale=es HTTP/1.1" 503 409 "http://www.ecozap.es/?locale=es" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/5
37.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36" www.ecozap.es
2014-01-28T09:31:47.240108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/?
locale=es host=www.ecozap.es request_id=cf3976b7-4c4b-4d11-b3dd-036cfc5c1ddb fwd="87.218.164.248" dyno=
connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-28T09:31:50.354991+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 5.10.83.26 - - [28/Jan/2014:09:31:50 +0000] "GET /carts/
918632?locale=es HTTP/1.1" 503 409 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot
/)" www.ecozap.es
2014-01-28T09:31:50.335416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/c
arts/918632?locale=es host=www.ecozap.es request_id=7f03696d-14bb-422c-befa-48cf359ab21f fwd="5.10.83.26
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-28T09:30:08.610174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/?locale=es host=www.ecozap.es
request_id=7e7f92e3-94ad-47a0-9154-90655af1633c fwd="87.218.164.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=125m
s status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-28T09:30:09.487341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/bg-e370e1a45db2fb66fee9
eb2ac688e649.png host=www.ecozap.es request_id=15ef80ef-0429-4f81-bf21-dca347746082 fwd="87.218.164.248"
 dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-28T09:30:09.167444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/CO2-plus-abfd84d445691d
3ace3d797cee661210.jpg host=www.ecozap.es request_id=bd87c4ae-90f3-4c27-a245-c79a836ea13e fwd="87.218.16
4.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-28T09:30:09.521797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/eco-253306c2a7299a16c10
9b71d8374e37c.jpg host=www.ecozap.es request_id=f58b7f21-e986-4e56-a668-257df0fc39b1 fwd="87.218.164.248
" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-28T09:30:09.464954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/eco-over-83ea6faa95bd9d
c45c1237aeb4624d00.jpg host=www.ecozap.es request_id=2979b3a4-e8d8-4cbc-94b1-253531753fa4 fwd="87.218.16
4.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-01-28T09:30:09.460994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/women-over-44ae6e42fc1e
999038afe5485af27c60.jpg host=www.ecozap.es request_id=708ee385-433b-49e8-a3c1-e8342408fbe9 fwd="87.218.
164.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0

C:\Sites\ecozap>
```

Comment: If you only changed styling and such, you shouldn't need to migrate database.

Comment: Serigo, before push my app to heroku, I tested my app in production mode, it works perfectly if its in the development mode, but in production mode I'm getting following error activerecord -3.1.11 Could not find table (ActiveRecord::Statement Invalid).

Comment: In other post someone told me that is necessary to migrate to resolve this error.

Comment: @FrankyCutty, Have you used the common database for development and production on local?

Comment: @FrankyCutty: did you use production mode on a local machine? It uses different database which probably doesn't exist locally yet (but should exist on heroku) (appname_production vs appname_development)

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I think that I'm using SQLite in development mode and Postgress in production mode. This is my gemfile: `group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '= 2.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '= 2.7.1'
  gem 'rspec'
  #gem 'annotate-models'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => 'ruby'
end`

Comment: This is the production mode `group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'uglifier'
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No It's not necessary to migrate the db for update and push the app on heroku.

The migration part is differentiated from deployment so you can easily deploy without migrating.

EDIT:
*Assuming you just want to test the production environment in your local*

Change your database.yml to use the same database as development. This way you don't need to change your gemfile and you can test production environment using your development environment

**Important: Rollback to your original database.yml after compliting testing**

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

staging:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/staging.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3 #<==This is the change
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: In other post someone told me that is necessary to migrate to resolve this error. [this is the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232643/error-with-activerecord-3-1-11-could-not-find-table-activerecordstatement-in). I´m confused.

Comment: @Franky, I think you should consider *Marek Lipka*'s answer(in your above given link) and edit the database.yml to set your production database to be the same as development database. In this way you would also able to test the app in production env. on local

Comment: @Uandl I didn't understand well the things I had to do. I edited the main post and I added the database.yml and my Gemfile. Thanks.

Comment: @Franky, I have updated my answer. I have assumed that you just want to test the production environment in your local. Please let me know if this is not the case.

And don't forget to discard this changes after testing

Comment: Ok @Uandl, I've changed the database.yml file like you told me, I've used `rails s -e production` command and everythings works properly. But the I want is to update the app to heroku, 
The client could manage the website using pg in production mode. I have problems to update the app regularly.

Comment: hm.. rollback to the original version of the `database.yml`. And after that I think it should be deployed on heroku without problem

Comment: @Uandl Like I told you, during update the app to heroku, it doesn't work and I get a pack of errors that I don't understand. I've edited the main post so you could see the errors.